# AD ConnectionString Failover Partner

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, active-directory, asp.net-mvc-5

Anyone knows how I can specify a backup LDAP connection in an AD ConnectionString in Web.Config? I have read about mirroring Database connection strings [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/677678/how-to-add-failover-partner-to-a-connection-string-in-vb-net)

Now I want to do something similar for ActiveDirectory connection string. Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I would think you could use this.

```
<add name="ADConnectionString" connectionString="LDAP://mySite.com/ou=useraccounts;LDAP_Failover://mySite_Failover.com/ou=useraccounts;DC=mySite,DC=com"/>
```