# .NET Entity Framework usage with replicated SQL servers

Tags: c#, vb.net, entity-framework-6

We have the following issue.

2 SQL Servers that are instant replicating there data. The 1st one we consider being our master server, the 2nd one backup server.

A long time ago we created a system similar to entity framework our self. This system was able to load/save all data from/to the master database and in case the master database wasn't available data was automatically loaded/saved from/to the backup. Using replication data was synchronised when the master got back online. It was even possible to load data from the master do some modifications and, in case master got offline, save it to the backup server.

Is the above possible in entity framework and how can we do this?
I can't find any examples on loading data from 1 database and in case of being offline switching to another database for saving.

We are using vb.net but I'm also understand C#.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do anything specific in Entity Framework, just set up connection string properly to use [failover partner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/677678/how-to-add-failover-partner-to-a-connection-string-in-vb-net#677702).